# JpaRepository getOne() fetches and updates whole object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, proxy, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to mimic this accepted SO answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39746931/3214777 to use a Hibernate Proxy when updating only a field of some objects.
My code looks like:

```
  @Transactional
public void updateStudentYear(int uniqueNumber, int newYear) {
    Student studentProxy = studentRepository.getOne(uniqueNumber);
    studentProxy.setYear(newYear);
    studentRepository.save(studentProxy);
}
```

The problem is that Hibernate does both a **full select** and a **full update**. Here be the logs:

> 2021-03-10 20:24:23.240 DEBUG 118757 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select student0_.unique_number as unique_n1_1_0_, student0_.name as name2_1_0_, student0_.team as team3_1_0_, student0_.year as year4_1_0_ from students student0_ where student0_.unique_number=?

> 2021-03-10 20:24:23.268 DEBUG 118757 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        : update students set name=?, team=?, year=? where unique_number=?

I was expecting that only one "**update year**" statement would be issued, but to my surprise, it looks that everything was done like a classic findOne()/save() pair of operation. Am I wrong?

Comment: It will only delay the execution of the select and probably because you haven't enabled partial updates it still is a full update. The accepted answer is the wrong answer (as you will also notice if you read the comments).

Comment: @M. Deinum then how could I enable partial uploads?

Comment: What has a partial upload to do with a partial update? If you only want partial updates, you can use the `@DynamicUpdate` annotation from Hibernate on your entities. Which will only issue an update query for the modified fields.

Comment: I meant partial updating, sorry. 'Twas a typo.

Comment: @M.Deinum ah there's a Hibernate specific annotation for that, thanks.

Comment: @DanielPop Partial update is not always a good thing, for example for caсhing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the answer in the linked question is wrong unfortunately. The `getOne()/getReference()` method isn't about updating individual fields, it's about avoiding hitting the database unless needed.

The usefulness of the method is in situations like

```
Foo foo = fooRepo.findOne(id);
Bar barProxy = barRepo.getOne(id);
foo.setBar(barProxy);
fooRepo.save(foo);
```

In this case `Foo` will be fetched from the db, but `Bar` will not.

JPA will always update all fields in the update statements, although I'm not sure if it can be affected with implementation's own [dirty checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8507922/jpa-dirty-checking). Hibernate has [@DynamicUpdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52162452/how-to-use-hibernate-dynamicupdate-with-spring-data-jpa) that limits the columns, but JPA doesn't specify a general mechanism for it.